# How are read and write socket errors defined in the wrk HTTP benchmarking tool?

Tags: sockets, tcp, wrk

I am using the [wrk HTTP benchmarking tool](https://github.com/wg/wrk) to test a server. And I am getting READ, WRITE as well as CONNECTION and TIMEOUT errors.

What I understand is:

- CONNECTION errors, are caused by the refusal of a TCP connection.
  Which could involve every element in the connection chain (Client,
  ISP and Server).
- TIMEOUT errors, are caused by the host failing to respond to a
  request within a certain time.

But what about READ and WRITE errors?

I would really appreciate, if someone could point me in the direction of a good resource?

Comment: Which tool and what does its documentation say about those terms?

Comment: wrk and wrk2, but I did not find any documentation regarding READ and WRITE errors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So what I understood from this [code from the WRK repository](https://github.com/wg/wrk/blob/50305ed1d89408c26067a970dcd5d9dbea19de9d/src/wrk.c) is that.

WRITE ERROR’s happen when attempting to write on a connection, but it fails because of a closed socket on the server.

READ ERROR’s happen when attempting to read on a connection, but it fails because of a closed socket on the server.

Happy if anybody can confirm or refute that.